# R linear model can't process values of 0

Tags: r, lm

I can't seem to get the `lm` function to work properly on any columns that have 0 as a data value. Here is my code:

```
project.lm = lm(SalePrice ~Lot.Area + Year.Built + Year.Remod.Add + Gr.Liv.Area +
                Yr.Sold + Bsmt.Unf.SF, project.table)
```

But when I do summary of `project.lm`, I get literally thousands of variables in my linear model, in fact one variable for each value of `Bsmt.Unf.SF`. This occurs for all columns where there is a value of 0; otherwise, everything works fine. Any ideas?!?

Comment: Your variables likely aren't stored as numbers, but as characters or factors. Verify by running `str(project.table)`. The problem isn't in `lm` but in the code you used to import your data.

Comment: ahhh that is exactly it! how would I read it in differently then? I simply did project.table = read.csv(url, header=T)

Comment: it sort of depends. R will try to get the data type right, but it depends on the data file being clean. Make sure numeric columns don't have any characters in them. You can convert columns after the fact with something like dat$newcol <- as.numeric(as.character(dat$oldcol))

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for `read.csv` and `read.table` : there's an argument called `stringsAsFactors` which is TRUE by default.  Set it to FALSE and you may be happier :-)

Comment: But strings would still need to be quantized before passing into lm.